# shared memory folder in Mac error shm: Invalid argument

Tags: c, macos, process, shared-memory

I usually code C in linux. I am using now a Mac and I am new on this machine.

In linux when I use shared memory between process, the memory is allocated as a file which pathname is */dev/shm/resource_name*.

I was trying a simple code and suddenly I got an error.
It wasn't able to call a function *destroy()* to destroy the shared memory.

Usually when this happens I delete the file manually on the directory.

My question is: Where is located the shared memory in OS X. Because when I try recompile and execute, the `gcc` compiler tells me that the resource already exists and I don't know how to delete it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int increment (int n)
{
  n = n + 1;
  printf ("%d\n", n);
  return n;
}

int *create ()
{
  int *ptr;
  int ret;

  int fd= shm_open ("/shm", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
  if (fd == -1) {
    perror ("shm");
    exit (1);
  }

  ret = ftruncate (fd, sizeof (int));
  if (ret == -1) {
    perror ("shm");
    exit (2);
  }

  ptr = mmap (0, sizeof (int), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd,   0);
  if (ptr == MAP_FAILED) {
    perror ("shm-mmap");
    exit (3);
  }
  return ptr;
}

void destroy (int *ptr)
{
  int ret;
  ret = munmap (ptr, sizeof (int));
  if (ret == -1) {
    perror ("shm");
    exit (7);
  }
  ret = shm_unlink ("shm");
  if (ret == -1) {
    perror ("shm");
    exit (8);
  }
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  sem_t *semaphore; 
  int *ptr = create ();
  int numProcessesChilds, numIncrements;
  int i;
  if (argc == 3) {
    numProcessesChilds = atoi (argv [1]);
    numIncrements = atoi (argv [2]);
  }
  else {
    numProcessesChilds = 10; 
    numIncrements = 1;
  }
  *ptr = 0;

  semaphore = sem_open("/semaphore", O_CREAT, 0xFFFFFFFF, 1);
  if (semaphore == SEM_FAILED) {
    perror("semaphore");
  }

  for (i = 0; i < numProcessesChilds; i++) {
    switch (fork ()) {
    case -1:
      perror ("fork");
      exit (1);
    case 0:
      sem_wait(semaphore);

      for (i = 0 ; i < numIncrements; i++) {
        (*ptr) = increment (*ptr);
      }
      sem_post(semaphore);
      exit (0);
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < numProcessesChilds; i++) {
    wait (NULL);
  }
  sem_close(semaphore);
  sem_unlink("/semaphore");

  printf ("Fina value: %d\n", *ptr);
  destroy (ptr);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you do any research before coding and then asking here?

Comment: *What* error do you get? What does `perror` tell you? And *which* of the two system calls in `destroy` is it that fails?

Comment: It is optional to have filesystem access to IPC objects... IPC have their own namespace. Write your own command to remove a given IPC. For SYSV IPC you can use `ipcrm` command, I think that there is no POSIX equivalent command (am I right?).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I got shm: Invalid argument

Comment: Notice, you're using `/shm` to create and `shm` (no backslash) to close... also, on Mac OS X "[There is no visible entry in the file system for the created object in this implementation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/shm_open.2.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/2/shm_open)" (from the `man` page).

Comment: @Myst Thanks: Didn't notice , but still get the same error!

Comment: Could `munmap` be the one returning an error? try writing a different `perror` identifier for each... P.S. please edit your question with the actual error message (I know it's in the comments, but providing the error code in the question is a better practice).

Comment: @Myst the same. I fixed with other way. Give a new name to the memory "/shm1" and in the function destroy I used other variable to to the munmap and the shm_unlink but I gave as argument the name "/shm". create and close "/shm1" and closed "/shm". It's not the best idea but it works

Answer (score 1):

Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73752984/14393739), Mac OS being derived from BSD does not expose any entry in the file system for shared memory objects. The corresponding files in */dev/shm* are Linux specific.

Under Mac OS, only `shm_unlink()` will do the cleanup job. The OP's example program should work upon each startup as it passes **O_CREAT** flag to `shm_open()`. If the shared memory object does not already exist, it is created otherwise it is opened as it is. As the resulting memory area pointed by *ptr* is reset with the instruction `*ptr = 0` at the beginning of the program, everything should work properly.

Answer (score -1):

Mac OS X , like linux is UNIX based so it handles the shared memory just like Linux. The shared memory segments you allocate are also files located in /dev/shm

To destroy the shared memory you can use the command `ipcs -m` or `ipcs -M` to view all the shared memory, look for yours and then execute `ipcrm -m shmid` where shmid would be the id of your shared memory. You can also do `ipcrm -M shmkey` using the key you assigned to it

Comment: Yes I already did that but its empty and when I execute again I get          shm: Invalid argument. And if I change the memory's name, for example, to "/shm1" runs perfectly. But I can't use "shm" as memory name. This means that shared memory still there am I right?

Comment: Yes you are, but it's weird you dont't get any results. Try ipcs -m or ipcs -M .

Comment: Yes the same. I just created a new shared memory with different name. When i destroy it I used the same pointer to delete the old one shared memory and it worked.

Comment: `man ipcs` says that it's for System V ipc, but OP is asking about shm_open which is POSIX shared memory.  Should `ipcs` work for both?

Comment: @Nevado This is quite old, but I was reading on the man page that you must call `shm_unlink` and close all open file descriptors (by ending your process or otherwise) to remove the shared memory. It's likely that `ipcrm` does this.